# Distance function between elements of different sets

Tags: functions, terminology

Let's say I have a set $X$ and a set $O$ and I am able to define a distance function $d(x,o)\in\mathbb R, x\in X, o\in O$. The only condition I place on $d$ is $d(x,o)>0$. So obviously it is no a metric, since metric calculates distances between elements of the same set and also has some more conditions it must fulfill. Also, I think, it is not a premetric, because $x$ and $o$ are from different sets. Is there a name for such a function or is distance function the correct (and only) name?

Background: In my case, in one application $o\subset X$, but in some applications $o$ is something completely different.

Comment: What you're describing is a function $X \times O \to \mathbb R_{>0}$. I'm not aware that this has a name, and it seems to me like a much too general notion to warrant one.

Comment: @user: Sure, but a "set function" also has a name and it is pretty general. That is why I thought this might also have name.